# Are jackrabbit object content mapping and org.springmodules.jcr dying?

Tags: java, spring, jackrabbit, jcr

I was wondering about this. I'm planning to employ jackrabbit in a ECM project and it seems that [OCM](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/5-with-jackrabbit-ocm.html) is dying or what, it is a different fork that the rest of the project. In maven repos there are old `jackrabbit-ocm-nodemanagement` `jackrabbit-ocm` versions, otherwise the project itself is downloadable via a referenced zip archive in reference documentation.

org.springmodules.jcr  didn't make it to the official spring source base. It got abandoned. Even though it was a great glue for jackrabbit OCM and the project looks great. I absolutely don't understand why they decided to leave such an important specification !?!?!?

It currently resides [here](https://github.com/astubbs/spring-modules) as some sort of conservation.
Also there is a [jcr spring extension](http://se-jcr.sourceforge.net/) that the same thing I suppose. It has its [Jira section](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEJCR), but everything seems abandoned to me. If I got into problems with some nasty bug, any support wouldn't get to me.

Please if you have brighter information than I do, let me know.

Comment: Maybe it's because OCM frameworks on top of JCR don't really have much value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370557/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-my-pojos-into-jackrabbit-jcr/371152#371152